# Why does jdbcTemplate convert column names to uppercase?

Tags: spring, jdbc, ojdbc

Why does jdbcTemplate convert column names to uppercase when I want them to return like this?

```
select bkId, restType, printTemplateId, positionNo, isConfirmNeed, isActive from RestTypeBkView order by bkId
```

Finds records, but returns uppercase names (example:BKID,RESTYPE....) rather than (example:bkId,restType). You do not need to change anything in the request. What could be the problem?Database oracle

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL column names are case-insensitive by definition. You can't rely on a JDBC connection, or even a database, to preserve column name case. Try

```
desc {table_name};
```

on Oracle, and you'll see the column names reported in upper-case, whatever you used when you created the table.

The Oracle database driver generally returns column names as they are known by the database -- that is, in upper-case. If you know what the column names *should* be, you can always write code to display more suitable values.

Comment: `SQL column names are case-insensitive by definition`- this is a) RDBMS dependent and b) definitvely **not true** for Oracle, which relitivates your following propositions... Please update.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber -- s5.2.13 of SQL92 requires 'reqular' and 'delimited' identifiers to be considered without regard for case. The OP does not use, or mention, quoted identifiers. Oracle _stores_ column names in upper case and that part is, indeed, implementation dependent.  However, my point is that a programmer cannot rely on column names being stored or interpreted with regard to case (leaving aside quoted identifiers). Your answer says the same as mine, but mine is shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all JDBCTemplate **does not convert column names to uppercase**.

If you defines your query such as follows

```
String sql = 'SELECT  bkId   FROM tab';
```

the Oracle database receives the very same (unconverted) string.

The point you address is the *interpretation* of the column names in the Oracle database.

An unquoted column name is *implicitely* considered as an uppercase name.

Example

```
create table tab 
(bkId number);

select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TAB';

COLUMN_NAME                   
------------------------------
BKID
```

But as stated above, you may *reference* the column in *lower case*or any combination of *lower and upper case*

Th equeries below are all fine and reference the column name `BKID`:

```
SELECT  bkId  FROM tab;
SELECT  BKID  FROM tab;
SELECT  bkid  FROM tab;
```

If you realy want a *case sensitive* column name, double quote the column name on creation:

```
create table tab 
("bkId" number); 

select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TAB';

COLUMN_NAME                   
------------------------------
bkId
```

But *think twice* if this is realy what you want, because this query will now fail

```
SELECT  bkId  FROM tab;

ORA-00904: "BKID": invalid identifier
```

You must quote the column name to be able to select it:

```
SELECT "bkId"  FROM tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution:
   <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

see package org.springframework.core CollectionFactort.java

```
/** Whether the Commons Collections 3.x library is present on the classpath */
    private static final boolean commonsCollections3Available =
            ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap",
                    CollectionFactory.class.getClassLoader());
/**
     * Create a linked case-insensitive Map if possible: if Commons Collections
     * 3.x is available, a CaseInsensitiveMap with ListOrderedMap decorator will
     * be created. Else, a JDK {@link java.util.LinkedHashMap} will be used.
     * @param initialCapacity the initial capacity of the Map
     * @return the new Map instance
     * @see org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap
     * @see org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap
     */
    public static Map createLinkedCaseInsensitiveMapIfPossible(int initialCapacity) {
        if (commonsCollections3Available) {
            logger.trace("Creating [org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap/CaseInsensitiveMap]");
            return CommonsCollectionFactory.createListOrderedCaseInsensitiveMap(initialCapacity);
        }
        else {
            logger.debug("Falling back to [java.util.LinkedHashMap] for linked case-insensitive map");
            return new LinkedHashMap(initialCapacity);
        }
    }
```